# iOS - Detecting if an URL stream is working or not, with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, avplayer, avplayeritem

This is how in my code, playing from url, looks like:

```
private func play() {
    let streamUrl = ...        
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: streamURL)
    radioPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    radioPlayer.volume = 1.0
    do {
         try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
         try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
         UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
     } catch {
         print("Error deactivating audio session.")
     }
     radioPlayer.play()
     startListeningForStreamFail()
     stopStartButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "pause_btn"), for: .normal)
}
```

---

Like the code snippet explains above, after calling the `.play()` function, I'm calling `startListeningForStreamFail()`, which registers the current viewcontroller to two types of notifications, on main thread.

```
private func startListeningForStreamFail() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self as Any, selector: #selector(self?.playerItemFailedToPlay), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled, object: self?.radioPlayer?.currentItem)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self as Any, selector: #selector(self?.playerItemFailedToPlay), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime, object: self?.radioPlayer?.currentItem)
    }
}
```

---

And the selector functions is this:

```
@objc private func playerItemFailedToPlay(notification: Notification) {
    print("playerItemFailedToPlay")
}
```

---

Because **the stream** right now **works** fine, I'm trying to test failure by **addig some plus characters** in it's url. But the `playerItemFailedToPlay()` functions does NOT get called, does NOT print anything.

Should this selector getting called, even if only the url was changed?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I built a testing project for you on [github](https://github.com/omiz/StreamTesterPlayer) try to test your link with it and please check the value of [NSAppTransportSecurity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40299837/6689101) in your project

Comment: Thank you for the test project and for your patience! 
I've tested my url, if the url is correct it works fine, but with the "fake" url does not get any error. I'm wondering if I get the same error code if 1. the url is valid (but stream doesn't work) and if 2. the url isn't valid.

Comment: I added a small trick to solve a fake url. please let me know if that works for you

Comment: In the `setup()` function if the url `!asset.isPlayable` I've changed the completion value from `nil` to `.unvalidURL`. And now it works. I've understood your logic, thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried to build a project on [Github](https://github.com/omiz/StreamTesterPlayer) for an easy check

I followed these steps:

1. Adding NSAppTransportSecurity to info.plist as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40299837/6689101) to allow http
2. Trim the provided url to remove any spaces

   `let urlString = urlString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)`
3. Check if the string provides a valid link

   `guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return complete(.unvalidURL) }`
4. Check if the link is playable

   `AVAsset(url: url).isPlayable`

If any of the previous steps was not successful then it means the url is not valid

I also added an observers for the errors after starting a playable link

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(itemFailedToPlayToEndTime(_:)), name: .AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
        
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(itemNewErrorLogEntry(_:)), name: .AVPlayerItemNewErrorLogEntry, object: nil)
        
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(itemPlaybackStalled(_:)), name: .AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled, object: nil)
```

EDIT:

The part of `AVAsset(url: url).isPlayable` might only check if the path ends with an appropriate extension as an example mp3, mp4.
I do not have access to check the actual code so I would only refer to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasset/1385974-isplayable)

Comment: above notification observers do not get called....can someone provide any solution for this

Comment: .isPlayable is utterly useless - all it does is check if the url ends in ".m3u8" or ".mp4".

Comment: @Fattie thank you for your comment but I was only following the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasset/1385974-isplayable) which says: `This property value is true if you can use the asset to create an AVPlayerItem.`

Comment: hi @zombie For sure - I wasn't criticizing you.  Exactly as the documentation says, **the only thing .isPlayable does  is check if the url ends in ".m3u8" or ".mp4"** (or other appropriate strings).  It's just a string checker.  It does not in any way check if the url is real, if the site actually exists on the internet, if the file is actually a video etc.  "isPlayable" simply means "can I play that type of file extension" - that's all it does.  it does not "go to the internet" in any way whatsoever, it's just a string checker.

Comment: the "observer" part of your answer is critical and excellent BTW!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Many of comments here says that `.isPlayable` it's just strings checker, but it's not.

In my case, I have 2 urls where video in one of them is broken, but both urls is correct.

After async loading of asset I have the next results:

```
asset=videoSource Optional("https://my.backend.com/7e84dd.mp4")
asset=isPlayable true

asset=videoSource Optional("https://my.backend.com/57f5d0.mp4")
asset=isPlayable false
```

So, its not just string checker